# bootstrap form gives html validation error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

creating a bootstrap form and while validating on WC3 I get this error: Error: Element lable not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 75, column 29; to line 75, column 83

```
      <lable class="form-check-lable pl-2" for="other-adult">Other
```

But this is the structure that Bootstrap uses, placing the  inside a div. What is 'correct'?

Comment: What does From line 75, column 29; to line 75, column 83 indicate?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is spelling error. You have `<lable>` but I'm assuming it is supposed to be `<label>` instead.

Comment: Thanks Dean, sorry for the Typo, I'm using Dreamweaver so once I type <la it autocompletes the tag, correctly <label>